# Get Array Path as string by php

Tags: php, laravel

I have arrays like this

> $InternetGatewayDevice['DeviceInfo'][0]['SoftwareVersion'][1]['_value']

and also like this

> $InternetGatewayDevice['DeviceInfo'][1]['SoftwareVersion'][2]['_value']

actually, both of them return same value,  which is the software version for the router,  but because routers belong to different vendors, I have that problem, so
actually, I want to know the path that I have to  go in, in order to get my value
so I  want to have somethings like this

> InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.0.SoftwareVersion.1._value

as a string
I mean I want a function where I  can provide to it the array and the key ,so  the function will return to me the path of the array that I have to follow in order to get the value like this

```
getpath($array,"SoftwareVersion")
```

whhich will return value like this

> InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.0.SoftwareVersion

are there any way to do this in php ?or laravel  package
or is there any way in PHP to get the value whatever the number key is?
I mean like this

```
$InternetGatewayDevice['DeviceInfo'][*]['SoftwareVersion'][*]
```

so what ever the key it will return the value

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use he **data_get** helper function provided by Laravel.

```php
public function getSoftwareVersion(array $data, int $deviceInfoIndex, int $softwareVersionIndex)
{
    $index = "DeviceInfo.{$deviceInfoIndex}.SoftwareVersion.{$softwareVersionIndex}";

    return data_get($data, $index);
}
```

Then it can be used like

```php
$softwareVersion = getSoftwareVersion($internetGatewayDevice, 1, 0);
```

[Laravel Docs - Helpers - Method data_get](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-data-get)

Comment: you gave me actually the idea of what  I  looking for data_get($my_arr, '*.lower');  actually I was looking for somethings like wildcard

Comment: @muhammadahmed Yes **data_get** supports wildcard as well as default value. The reason I included the link to Laravel Docs is so that you can tweak the approach to satisfy your exact requirement.

Comment: many thanks ,  but I have a question plz ,  do u  know how can I get the path of returned value from array ?

Comment: @muhammadahmed You get a value from deeply nested array only once you know the path. If you want to, for some reason, record or get the path (in dot notation) used to fetch data via **data_get** you can return the same from the function where you are constructing the path eg: `return ['path' => $index, 'value' => data_get($data, $index)];`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the get function from lodash php
https://github.com/lodash-php/lodash-php

Example:

```
<?php
 use function _\get;

$sampleArray = ["key1" => ["key2" => ["key3" => "val1", "key4" => ""]]];
get($sampleArray, 'key1.key2.key3');
// => "val1"

get($sampleArray, 'key1.key2.key5', "default");
// => "default"

get($sampleArray, 'key1.key2.key4', "default");
// => ""
```

Comment: are there any way to set the key as dynamic ,  as I  explained the key sometimes  will be  0 and sometimes will be 1 or 2 so I  want to get the value  by range of numbers

Comment: yes you can, like that: get($sampleArray, 'key1.key2[0].key5', "default");

Comment: and if you to set, you can the set method instead of the get method

Comment: like this  $InternetGatewayDevice['DeviceInfo'][*]['SoftwareVersion'][*]  * mean any number or any key

Comment: I don't know  what is key2 will be ,  it can be  0, 1 or 2 or even 3 ,  so I  want  to  have a range like this     get($sampleArray, 'key1.*.key2.*.key3', "default");

Comment: in that case you can add the index in your string, "key${index}"....

Comment: can u explain please with my  example ?

Comment: ${index}.WANConnectionDevice.${index}.WANPPPConnection.${index}.X_HW_VLAN._value    I applied it like this but it is not working

Comment: are there any way to use REGEX in this package ? like this regex:[0-5].WANConnectionDevice.regex:[0-5].WANPPPConnection.regex:[0-5].X_HW_VLAN._value